# Firebase Query not working swift no results

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can't get this to work for the life of me. It never returns a result. Help would be appreciated.

CODE:

```
let ref1 = Database.database().reference().child("profiles").child("zig__zag_@hotmailcom").queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue : "Simon Lacasse")

ref1.observe(.value, with:{ (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
    for snap in snapshot.children {
        print((snap as! DataSnapshot).key)
    }
})
```

Database Structure:
[image]

Firebase rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "profiles": {

        ".indexOn": ["name"]

    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do the same thing twice:

```
let ref1 = Database.database().reference().child("profiles").child("zig__zag_@hotmailcom").queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue : "Simon Lacasse")
```

You're first going to `/profiles/zig__zag_@hotmailcom` (a specific user's node) and then querying all child nodes under there for the ones that have a property `name` equal to `Simon Lacasse`. If you check `/profiles/zig__zag_@hotmailcom` you'll see that its child nodes are already individual properties, so you're one level too deep into the JSON tree.

Either you need to do a direct lookup:

```
let ref1 = Database.database().reference().child("profiles").child("zig__zag_@hotmailcom")
ref1.observe(.value, with:{ (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
    print(snapshot.key)
})
```

No loop is needed in this case, since you're already looking up the precise node that you want to load.

Or you do a query for child nodes matching the name:

```
let ref1 = Database.database().reference().child("profiles").queryOrdered(byChild: "name").queryEqual(toValue : "Simon Lacasse")
ref1.observe(.value, with:{ (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
    for snap in snapshot.children {
        print((snap as! DataSnapshot).key)
    }
})
```

Here the loop is needed, since there might potentially be multiple child nodes matching the query.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your quick feedback. I've tried both and it still never gets into printing the snap. So I'm assuming it never comes back with a result. Could it be something with my rules?

Comment: Your rules look fine. In the first snippet, the `print` should *always* run. If not, you're likely not connected to the network or Firebase.

Comment: played around with all day. Here is what is happening, first it runs twice, no idea why, first time it doesnt find anything, then the second time it runs it finds it.

Comment: That sounds like you either have local persistence enabled, or are attaching the same listener multiple times. But neither of those are related to the code changes in my answer.

Comment: ok figured it out... asynchronous, needed to put checks inside the { }